# Regex replace with html tags in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I am using Angular JS to get and `ng-repeat` over Twitter tweets. I needed to highlight parts of the tweet string, like `@tag` and `#hash`, so it was suggested I use `replace` to add DOM wrappers around the things I want to highlight.

The issue is, since I'm not directly outputting to the DOM, and instead `ng-repeating` over a scope variable, the html tags don't seem to be added to the strings.

**Question**: How can I append html tags to a JS string?

---

Directive snippet:

```
scope.getTweets = function () {
    ModulesService.getTweets().success(function (res) {
        if (res && Array.isArray(res)) {
            scope.tweets = parseTweets(res);
        }
    });
};
scope.getTweets();
var parseTweets = function (tweets) {
    tweets.forEach(function (tweet) {
        tweet.text.replace(/(@[^ ]+)/g, '<a class="user">$1</a>').
        replace(/(#[^ ]+)/g, '<span class="hash">$1</span>').
        replace(/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
        console.log('tweet!', tweet.text); //does not contain altered HTML
    });
    return tweets;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tweet in tweets" class="post-body clearfix">
    {{tweet.text}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use filter like this

```
  filterExample.filter('filterName', function () {
    return function (text) {
    var str = text.replace(/(@[^ ]+)/g, '<a class="user">$1</a>').
    replace(/(#[^ ]+)/g, '<span class="hash">$1</span>').
    replace(/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
        return str.toLowerCase();
    };
 })
```

and in html

```
  <div ng-repeat="tweet in tweets" class="post-body clearfix">
      <span ng-bind-html="tweet.text | filterName"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is great! Angular renders them as escaped. How can I unescape them so they render as HTML tags?

Comment: require to import the sanitize module and js file

Comment: There is no good reason to use a filter here; they run on every digest loop and can be a real drag on performance.  Filters should only be used when the data is likely to change frequently enough to make that worthwhile -- in this case you'd be much better off pre-parsing the tweets as you were doing originally, rather than constantly re-running those regexes in a filter. Srinivasan A and OscarJ's answers (combined) would solve your issue without introducing performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the replace method doesn't change the string but returns a new string with the replacements. Change your code to:

```
tweet.text = tweet.text.replace(...).replace(...)...;
```

Secondly `{{tweet.text}}` gets replaced by html escaped text. Change it to:

```
<span ng-bind-html="tweet.text"></span>
```

Comment: As per @Daniel's comment I've added @Srinivasan's solution to mine, except I used `<span>` rather than `<p>` as the latter generally has the side effect of adding white-space to the result as rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ng-bind-html?

```
 <div ng-repeat="tweet in tweets" class="post-body clearfix">
   <p ng-bind-html="tweet.text"></p>
</div>
```