# How to remove double quotes on link title attributes using expression data?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to pass the link title attribute for `"Tags"`.

The Tag value should be an array now I am tried to remove double quotes on link title attribute.

When I hover currently I am getting :-`["text", "text 1", "text 2"]`.

But expected format (Text Capitalized Case):- `[Text, Text 1, Text 2]`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="" ng-controller="myCrtl">
    <span>Heading Documents</span>
    <ul ng-repeat="list in names">
        <li ng-repeat="lists in list.bookmarks">
            <a href="{{lists.link}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{lists.tags}}">{{lists.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS File:**

```
var app=angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller('myCrtl',["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.names=[{
        "description": "Testing File",
        "totalCount": 6,
        "bookmarks": [{
                "title": "Google",
                "link": "https://www.google.co.in",
                "tags": [
                    "text", "text 1", "text 2"
                ]
            },

            {
                "title": "Test Construction1",
                "link": "http://google.com",

                "tags": [
                    "content", "content 2", "content 3"
                ]
            },
             {
            "title": "Test Connection",
            "link": "https://www.google.com",
            "tags": [
                "message", "message 1"
            ]
        }
        ]

    }];
}]);
```

Comment: catch " with regex before returning the names[]?

Comment: @Harry: pls guide me i am new to this

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704715/regex-replace-with-html-tags-in-directive/35704890#35704890

Comment: you can do this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string on each item in your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `["text", "text 1", "text 2"]` is because you're displaying an array with string in it; if you want a string that looks like `[Text, Text 1, Text 2]` then you can pipe the output through a function:

```
  $scope.change = function(a){
     a = a.map(function(x){
        return x.replace(/^[a-z]/,function(m){
            return  m.toUpperCase()
        });
     });
    return "["+a.join()+"]";
  };
```

and in your view you just use it like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="list in names">                                  
<li ng-repeat="lists in list.bookmarks">
  <a href="{{lists.link}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{change(lists.tags)}}">{{lists.title}}</a></li>

</ul>
```

### [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lojopaxute/1/edit?html,js,output)

---

you could also use angular filters to do it, but in the end the concept is : **filter the data to obtain a modified output.**